# Sorting a complex array in Java

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a problem sorting the contents of a 2D integer array (not ArrayList) in Java. My problem array `path_info[ ][ ]` looks something like this:

```
Node_x Node_y Path_ID Port_x Port_y
  4      6      500     3       2
  6      8      500     3       2      
  4      9      501     2       3
  9      3      501     2       2      
  2      3      502     3       2      
  1      5      503     2       3 
  5      2      503     2       2
```

Each row means: node_x to node_y on Path_ID through Port_x to Port_y. Please note, each path can be one or more rows in the table.

This array is the resultant array from a routing algorithm to reach node 1 from node 8 on an undirected unweighted graph.

To reach from a source node to a destination node; for example node 1 from node 8 in the table, the path_IDs are 500, 501, 502 and 503 (PATH_IDs already sorted in column `Path_ID`). The problem is that I want this array to be sorted in such a way that the source node is the first node of the column "Node_x" and the destination node is the last node .of the column "Node_y". And all the intermediate rows and columns sorted appropriately.

The resultant array should look like this (when source node is 8 and destination node is 1):

```
Node_x Node_y Path_ID Port_x Port_y
  8      6      500     2      3
  6      4      500     2      3     
  4      9      501     2      3
  9      3      501     2      2
  3      2      502     2      3
  2      5      503     2      2
  5      1      503     3      2
```

I have not started writing code yet so do not have a snippet to paste. I am still trying to figure out how to achieve this. Could someone please help me?

Comment: This is not so much an "array" as a graph, correct? You may want to read about [Eulerian paths](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eulerian_path)

Comment: @user144 I really don't understand your question.

Comment: @durron597 Why are you comming up with Euler paths? Maybe I missed something in the Question?

Comment: @user1449265 Do you need and algorithm for shortest path problem? Or what are your critereas for sorting the array? So in my opinion you are not sorting an array.

Comment: @Robin: The array has been deduced from Dijkstra's algorhtim which gave me the Path_IDs. I only need to sort the array in format I illustrated above.

Comment: @durron597: Yes this is a sub-graph, but it is represented as a simple 2D array. The current problem I am facing is just the sorting in the way I explained. I am sorry I did not know how else to elaborate in words than giving an example.

Comment: @user1449265 Besides I can't see the 2d structure in your Question, you should go with AlexR's Answer. This will be the solution for your problem. Check this as an Explanation: http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Comment: @Robin AlexR's answer won't work, because he needs to link front to back

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your algorithm worked correctly, you shouldn't ever be visiting the same node more than once. So you can just greedily look for the right nodes, but you need a good data structure so you don't loop incessantly. This code assumes that `path_info[index][0]` is `node_x`, and `path_info[index][1]` is `node_y`. Try something like this, which runs in `O(n)` time for each loop:

```
import java.util.*;

public class GraphSorter {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] graph = new int[][]{{9, 3}, {6, 4}, {3, 2}, {8, 6}, {5, 1}, {4, 9}, {2, 5} }; 
    LinkedList<int[]> myList = path(graph, 8);
    for (int[] edge : myList) {
      System.out.println(Arrays.toString(edge));
    }
  }

  public static LinkedList<int[]> path(int[][] path_info, int source) {
    HashMap<Integer, int[]> nodeXmap = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
    HashMap<Integer, int[]> nodeYmap = new HashMap<Integer, int[]>();
    LinkedList<int[]> foundPath = new LinkedList<int[]>();

    for(int i = 0; i < path_info.length; i++) {
      // We already found an edge with this node_x edge, turn it around
      if(nodeXmap.containsKey(path_info[i][0])) {
        int tmp = path_info[i][0];
        path_info[i][0] = path_info[i][1];
        path_info[i][1] = tmp;
      }
      nodeXmap.put(path_info[i][0], path_info[i]);
      nodeYmap.put(path_info[i][1], path_info[i]);
    }

    int current = source;
    // Use our maps to lookup where the next edge exists in our path,
    // since our input is guaranteed to be unique
    for(int i = 0; i < path_info.length; i++) {
      int[] currentEdge = nodeXmap.get(current);
      if (currentEdge == null) {
        currentEdge = nodeYmap.get(current);
        current = currentEdge[0];
      } else {
        current = currentEdge[1];
      }
      foundPath.add(currentEdge);
      nodeXmap.remove(currentEdge[0]);
      nodeYmap.remove(currentEdge[1]);
    }

    return foundPath;
  }
}
```

Comment: @user1449265 This works, but it assumes that your input is correct. I make no guarantees that it will work with bad edges.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Arrays.sort()` with custom comparator that works with one-dimentional array (element of your 2D array)

Comment: Thank you for your response. My problem is to figure out what logic I need to use to sort. So even if I would use a comparator I would have to implment a logic, which is what I am unable to figure out, yet.

Comment: I think you described your logic into your answer. Just implement it. Iterate over the sub-array and compare numbers until they are equal. Once one of the numbers is not equal to appropriate number in other array return -1 or +1. If you arrived to the end both arrays are equal, so return 0.